# Is my Mac OSX mail connected?

Tags: macos, email, connection

Well, of course, you can't tell that yourself.  But more to the point, I haven't received mail in a couple of days and a test mail I sent has not shown up in my inbox.  So: how can I tell if my Mac OSX mail is connected to my organization's server?  And if not, how do I get it to connect?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the standard Mail.app that comes with macOS? If so, you can get a pretty good idea of the connection status by choosing Window menu > Connection Doctor.

Comment: @GordonDavisson   Thanks.  Seems to be just what I needed.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll be happy to hit the accept button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's Mail app has a built-in "Connection Doctor" that you can use to check connectivity to the server(s). If something's not working, it can also tell you a bit about what's going wrong. Choose Window menu > Connection Doctor, and just look for the red/green status indicators next to each server connection that Mail is configured to use. See [Apple support document #:HT204173, "Use Mail Connection Doctor"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204173) for more details.